# Groovy doesn't infer the return type of a method

Tags: groovy, type-inference, return-type, typechecking

I'm trying to type check a simple Groovy script:

```
@groovy.transform.TypeChecked
class C {
    def fn() { return "result" }
    def ln() { return fn().length() }
}
new C().ln()
```

My expectation would be that the `fn` method's would be inferred to `String`, however when I try to run the script I get an error:

```
_GroovyUserScript_: 4: [Static type checking] - Cannot find matching method java.lang.Object#length(). Please check if the declared type is correct and if the method exists.
 @ line 4, column 23.
       def ln() { return fn().length() }
                         ^

1 error
```

Meaning the return type for the method was inferred to be `java.lang.Object`. Now, if I change the script to

```
@groovy.transform.TypeChecked
    ...
    String fn() { return "result" }
    ...
```

the script is compiled correctly.

However, I've noticed that the following script also compiles correctly:

```
@groovy.transform.TypeChecked
class C {
    def fn() { return "result" }
}
def x() {
    new C().fn().length()
}
x()
```

So maybe the problem is that type inference is not transitive between methods of the same class for some reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In groovy `def` equals to `Object` so, the first case correctly fails.

And `@groovy.transform.TypeChecked` checks only class or method that it annotates. in second case the method `def x(){...}` is not annotated (it's declared out of class).
So, no validation performed at compilation step.